# Sampling from kNN density estimate

Tags: sampling, nonparametric, k-nearest-neighbour

Is there an easy/standard way of sampling from a density estimated by kNN? I've searched online but I can't seem to find how to do this. Any links or methods pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Just to clarify, I would want to be able to sample points not (necessarily) in my dataset from the estimated density that I get using kNN on the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [rejection sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling)? Given your estimated density $f(x)$ you will need to find another density $g(x)$ which satisfies $f(x)<Mg(x)$. Then proceed with the algorithm described in a link. If your density $f(x)$ for example has bounded support, i.e. is zero outside and some interval $[a,b]$, you can simply use uniform distribution in $[a,b]$ as your density $g$. This method has its drawbacks, which again are listed in the wikipedia link.

Another possible solution is to calculate the cdf $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)dt$ and find its inverse $F^{-1}$. Then sample uniform random variables $U_i$ from interval $[0,1]$ and your sample from $f$ will be $X_i=F^{-1}(U_i)$.

The second approach should be computationally intensive, since you can find the inverse only by numerical methods. But then again it is not that hard to code.

These two approaches are general methods which apply to any density $f$. I would search the literature whether there are specific methods.